# styling in react is not visible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, css-loader

I am working on a third party pagination component in Reactjs.  and the npm package says to include
**import "rc-pagination/assets/index.css";** line on the file .

But the style is not getting applied. The style loader inject the *index.css* to the DOM but when doing inspect element , i cannot see the modularized classNames in the HTML Tags.

Here's my webpack config: **( i am using create-react-app v2)**

```
const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
        isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve("style-loader"),
        isEnvProduction && {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: Object.assign(
                {},
                shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths ? { publicPath: "../../" } : undefined
            ),
        },
        {
            loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
            options:{
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: "[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]"
            },
        },
        {
            // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
            // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
            // package.json
            loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
            options: {
                // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
                ident: "postcss",
                plugins: () => [
                    require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes"),
                    require("postcss-preset-env")({
                        autoprefixer: {
                            flexbox: "no-2009",
                        },
                        stage: 3,
                    }),
                ],
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
            },
        },
        {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
                implementation: require("node-sass")
            }
        },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
        loaders.push({
            loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
            options: {
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
            },
        });
    }
    return loaders;
};
```

[note:This is from create-react-app only]

```
    {
                        test: cssRegex,
                        exclude: cssModuleRegex,
                        use: getStyleLoaders({
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                        }),


                    {
                        test: cssModuleRegex,
                        use: getStyleLoaders({
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                            modules: true,
                            getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                        }),
                    },
```

```js
import React ,{ Component } from "react";
import Pagination from "rc-pagination";
import "rc-pagination/assets/index.css";

class WebsiteFooter extends Component {
    state = {
     current: 3,
    };
      onChange = (page) => {
       console.log(page);
       this.setState({
        current: page,
       });
      }
      render() {
       return (
        <div>
                  sxscs
         <Pagination
          onChange={this.onChange}
          current={this.state.current}
          total={80}
          showLessItems
          showTitle={false}
         />
        </div>
       );
      }
}

export default WebsiteFooter;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and this is how my DOM looks like :

[image: Th style loader injects]

[image: the class is not modularized]

Please help me ! I googled everything , but can't find anything.

Comment: What is your project structure? It seems like the problem is with the configuration. Configuration of loading css files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the webpack file, try change your css loader object to:

```
       {
        loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
        options:{
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: "[local]"
        }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much . But why **[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]**  this was an issue ?
 I want to  know

Comment: What this localndentName does is hashing the css classes.
this is helpful when you work on a big project and you dont want classes to overwrite eachother.

Comment: But if i don't put hash , then my style might get override if i choose the same className , and then that could be an issue ! 
I am working on big project xD
is there any other way around ?

Comment: it's `use: [
        "style-loader",
        { loader: "css-loader", options: { importLoaders: 1 } }
         ],`
not on the loader section , but on test section , actually i am using scss , so it directly uses the getStyleloader() which ultimatley hashes the file. 
For this project , for only on css file , i edited the **/\.css$/**  test in webpack with above lines
.This library wasn't accepting _postcss-loader_ so i removed it from line and also removed hash for the css files that are directly imported rather than scss. 
i have separate test case for **.scss** files

Comment: if im not mistaken i think you can import that on your scss file but wrap it with the :global and it would work aswell and still keep your hashing.
something like that - 
:global {
  @import "rc-pagination/assets/index.css";
}

Comment: like this => 
`.wrap {
    :global {
        @import "<mymodule>.scss";
    }
}`
so i then directly  import this in my websitefooter.scss. right ?
like import classes from "./sdsdsd.css'
<div classsName={classes.wrap}>

Answer (score 0):

After looking into your code looks like you have Pagination component where you should have applied CSS classes those defined in index.css, so you should import your index.css in pagination component and not in WebsiteFooter component.

I hope this will resolve your issue!